# Access JavaScript object in parent from iframe

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe, tinymce

I am creating an TinyMCE plugin which uses an iframe.  Withing the iframe defined by iframe.html, how do I access parentObject?  I've tried `window.top.parentObject`, but no luck.

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('image', function(editor, url) {

    var parentObject={'xxx':123};

    editor.addButton('image', {
        icon: 'image',
        onclick: function(){
            var tinyEditor=editor.windowManager.open({
                html: '<iframe src=iframe.html" id="plugin-id"></iframe>'
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: If you down vote, please comment why you did so.  Thank you

Comment: @anvoz. Yes, but still undefined.  If I move the declaration of parentObject outside of the plugin, however, it is defined using your solution as well as top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function body is a scope, and you're defining the variable inside a function. Move `var parentObject` to global scope and access it with `window.top.parentObject` or `window.parent.parentObject`.

Answer (score 1):

You're not able to access this object, because it is enclosed by your `function(editor, url) {...}`, whereas withing iframe you can access only parent window and all it's variables.
The only way is to move `parentObject` to global context.